# Incorrect argument for command at position x

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft snapshot [18w01a](https://minecraft.wiki/w/18w01a), the `/execute` command syntax has changed (actually this has been around since [17w45a](https://minecraft.wiki/w/17w45a), but that's not the point).

When I use the command `execute at @a[x=0,y=4,z=-0,dx=15,dy=1,dz=0] worldborder center 8.0, -8.0` Minecraft gives me an error message saying `Incorrect argument for command at position 44 ...[d]y=1,dz=0] <--[HERE]`.

The selector `@a[x=0,y=4,z=-0,dx=15,dy=1,dz=0]` uses correct syntax, so what is incorrect about the command?

Comment: I would recommend to replace `at` with `if`. You don't need to actually change the execution position and you don't need to do it multiple times if there are multiple entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new `execute` syntax, you must put `run` before the command you want to run, like this:

```
execute at @a[x=0,y=4,z=-0,dx=15,dy=1,dz=0] run worldborder center 8.0 -8.0
```

The error is saying that `worldborder` is not a valid argument for `execute`, as it's expecting an execute subcommand (`as`, `at`, etc.)